# Stick footer to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, css

How do I get the footer to stick to the bottom of the page if the main height is less than the document's height ?
https://planbuildr.com/login?skin=purple
At present I am doing this but I think it's wrong as the inner pages' (after logging in) footer is below the screen.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Change height of container
    if ($("#main").height() < $(document).height())
     $("#main").height($(document).height() - 152); // 132
});
</script>
```

I am not sure if I should a CSS only solution. I don't mind if JavaScript is used to detect height.

The HTML's code body with PHP code is like this :

```
<div id="container">
    <header style="background-color:#3264f2;height:43px">
        <?php require_once CB_DIR_UI.$CB['skin'].'/html/header.html'; ?>
    </header>

    <main id="main" style="width:calc(100% - 300px);margin:20px auto 0 auto;padding:10px;border:7.5px solid #666666;border-radius: 10px;background-color:#f6f7fa;overflow-y:auto">
        <?php require_once CB_DIR_UI.$CB['skin'].'/html/'.$CB['template_file']; ?>    
    </main>    

    <div class="clear"></div>    

    <footer style="margin-top:20px">
        <?php require_once CB_DIR_UI.$CB['skin'].'/html/footer.html'; ?>
    </footer>    

</div>
```

Comment: can you show us your html(relevant to answer your question)

Comment: This goal can be achieved by CSS only. See: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Comment: I have edited the post to include the HTML template.I used to follow pmob.co.uk but this was 10 years back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that only in css using flexbox. The second example show how it works when the content overflow the page.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

header, section, footer {
  padding: 8px;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>Header</header>
  <section>Content</section>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</main>
```

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    header, section, footer {
      padding: 8px;
    }

    section {
      flex: 1;
      background: silver;
    }
```

```html
<main>
  <header>Header</header>
  <section>
    Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>Content<br/>
  </section>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</main>
```

Comment: But if the main's height is more than the document's height then there's a scroll for the main. In that case I want the footer below the screen after the main. Is that possible ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean ? Is not the behavior shown in the 2nd example ? If you want the footer to be always visible despite the main height, you must use `position: fixed`.

Comment: See the content has a scroll - https://imgur.com/a/MtXhDF2 - that when the content's container is more in height than the document itself. In that case I want the footer below the screen after the main content.

Comment: This solved the problem though. `if ($("#container").height() < $(document).height())
$("#container").height("100vh"); // height:100vh;`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with CSS, no need for JS.

There are some ways to do it, but my favorite (cleaner) is the following:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-content-wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer-wrapper {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-content-wrapper">
    Your main content. Pushing the footer down.
  </div>

  <div class="footer-wrapper">
    Your footer content. Down here!
  </div>
</body>
```